# In Bash: How to parse a " " separated string?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, parsing

`echo "$options"` prints:

*"Package A" "Package B" "Package C"*

I'd like put that string into an array. I tried:

```
IFS='" "' read -a array <<< "$options"
```

but that didn't work out well: now the string is separated after every " and every [Space]. I guess everything between the `' '` of the IFS counts as separator.
Can anyone help me to parse the string that I'll have an array like

```
array[0]="Package A"
array[1]="Package B"
array[2]="Package C"
```

or

```
array[0]=Package A
array[1]=Package B
array[2]=Package C
```

thanks for advises

[**Edit**: actual state]
Here's what it looks right now

```
#! /bin/bash

function parseoutput() {

    array="${1}"

for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
    echo "-x-"
done
```

and

```
parseoutput "$options"
```

---

---

while `$options="Package A" "Package B" "Package C"` the output of the for loop just has one run, which is

```
"Package A" "Package B" "Package C"
-x-
```

so the whole string is in the first element of the array :/

Comment: `d=("Package A" "Package B" "Package C")` works to me. If I `echo "${d[1]}"` I get `Package B`.

Comment: You can just use `set "Package A" "Package B" ...` and they will be stored in $@ where $1 will be "Package A" and so forth... this is how you do "arrays" in Posix (not bash) shells without bashisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eval` to expand the variable and then parse everything into an array using `()`:

```
eval array=($options)
echo ${array[0]}
```

gives

```
Package A
```

Note that

```
array=($options)
```

also creates an array but one with 6 elements: `"Package`, `A"`, ...

**EDIT** How does this work?

In BASH, quotes help to turn white space into parts of a value.

```
a=(Package A)
```

would create an array with two elements. To get a single element, we need to quote the value:

```
a=("Package A")
```

Now `$options` already contains quotes. But when expanding variables, BASH doesn't parse the line twice. So after shell expansion, it sees

```
a=('"Package' 'A"')
```

(I'm using the single quotes to show how BASH breaks the input into words).

Here is a small shell script which demonstrates various ways to use the variable `$options`:

```
set -x
options='"A B" "C D"'
echo $options
echo "$options"

a=($options)
: ${#a[@]}
: ${a[@]}

eval a=($options)
: ${#a[@]}
: ${a[@]}

function a() {
    : "$@"
}

a "$options"
a $options
eval a $options
```

The output is:

```
+ options='"A B" "C D"'
+ : '"A' 'B"' '"C' 'D"'
+ : '"A B" "C D"'
+ a=($options)
+ : 4
+ : '"A' 'B"' '"C' 'D"'
+ eval 'a=("A' 'B"' '"C' 'D")'
++ a=("A B" "C D")
+ : 2
+ : A B C D
+ a '"A B" "C D"'
+ : '"A B" "C D"'
+ a '"A' 'B"' '"C' 'D"'
+ : '"A' 'B"' '"C' 'D"'
+ eval a '"A' 'B"' '"C' 'D"'
++ a 'A B' 'C D'
++ : 'A B' 'C D'
```

So to call your function, you need to use `eval` again. Afterwards, the arguments will be in `$1`, `$2`, ...

```
eval parseoutput $options
```

For this to work, the elements in `$options` must be quoted properly!!!

Comment: `declare "array=($options)"` should work as well, while being a little safer than `eval`.

Comment: please have a look at the original post, I added your suggested solution

Comment: the **only** solution that worked was the eval! thanks

Comment: @chepner: Did you try that? We need BASH to parse the line twice (which `eval` will do) to make sure the inner quotes become the main quotes that separate array elements. `declare` won't do this.

Comment: @user3085931: See my edits for a solution when you need to call a function

Comment: I really appreciate for your helpful support

Comment: @AaronDigulla Possibly? It looks like `options='"Package A" "Package B" "Package C"'; declare -a "array=$($options)"` will work (just tested it; I forgot the `-a` in my comment, apparently). After `bash` expands `$options` in the call, `declare` gets the literal string `array=("Package A" "Package B" "Package C")`.

Comment: @user3085931 It's safer because `eval` will execute *any* code that it finds, just as if it were typed directly. You have to be sure of the contents of `$options`. `declare`, on the other hand, doesn't execute code; it just does parameter assignment. Consider `options="); echo hello; x=("` followed by `eval "array=($options)"`.

Comment: Ah right I understand, but it's alright It's the output string of a --checklist. That output is always "abc 1" "def 2" "ghi 3"

Comment: @user3085931: Still be aware that an attacker might send you something evil.